# Get-AutomationPSCredential fails

Tags: azure-automation

When executing a runbook on a hybrid worker `Get-AutomationPSCredential` fails with: 
Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:Microsoft.PowerShell.DynamicActivities}Activity_935320357_Nested'.

Problem is only when running through Azure Automation, when I run it locally in ISE on the hybrid worker it works. Verified that module Orchestrator.AssetManagement.Cmdlets is available. `Get-AutomationVariable` works as expected.

```
workflow Test
{
  $SubscriptionName = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'VAR-AUTO-SubscriptionName'
  $SubscriptionName 
  $AzureAutomationCredential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'CRE-AUTO-AutomationUser'
  $AzureAutomationCredential 
}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing your runbook code?

Comment: `workflow Test  
{ $SubscriptionName = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'VAR-AUTO-SubscriptionName'
  $SubscriptionName 
  $AzureAutomationCredential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'CRE-AUTO-AutomationUser'
  $AzureAutomationCredential 
}`